# What does the comma before the conjunction "or" mean in the following sentence (i.e. "...Software, or to create a business...")?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

What does the comma before the conjunction "or" mean in the following sentence (i.e. "...Software, or to create a business...")?

You have no right to resell our Content or media from any source, as rendered by the Software, in any manner that we regard as being in competition with our Software, or to create a business of offering pre-rendered works or templates (whether offered for free or for payment) that are renderings or modifications of our Content or media from any source, and which may in fact compete with the Software or other Video Copilot products in our sole discretion.

Comment: [Best to ask a lawyer.](http://www.lawnow.org/comma-law/)

Answer (score 1):

The comma doesn't 'mean' anything as such. It separates  the two things that *you* have no right to do, **resell the content ...** and **create a business ...** .  In view of the two preceding commas, I would use a semi-colon instead of a comma here to mark a stronger break.